# getText().toString() arabic characters in Android

Tags: android, string, arabic

I have an edittext and a button. When i press the button the text from edittext is uploaded on a server using JSON. The JSON part is working with arabic language and stuff. I verified. When i get the value from mysql I can settext with arabic characters.

Thanks.

Edit: Ok. You were right. The problem is in php thing. The idea is that when I print in JSON and read from MYSql database it works to see arabic texts. But I can't post them.

So, I can read but I can't write in Arabic Language.

Comment: That's a problem with your server or database.

Comment: No it's not. I manually added a text from my php file and it works. I did set the Encoding in php and mysql.

Comment: Is the text displayed with arabic string in your edittext??

Comment: Yes, in edittext I can see the arabic characters. But in mysql, after i added them, I can not see them. The problem is at getText().toString...

Answer (score 0):

```
 Button buton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
 EditText editmessage =(EditText ) findViewById(R.id.button);

 button.setetOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
     String message = editmessage.getText().toString() 

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this but I do know Android. The problem is in the php file where I POST things to MYSQL.. It gives me "????" instead of Arabic word.